# How to sort the string 'MH/122020/[xx]x' in an Access query?

Tags: sql, sorting, ms-access

I am trying to sort the numbers,

```
MH/122020/101
MH/122020/2
MH/122020/145
MH/122020/12
```

How can I sort these in an Access query?

I tried `format(mid(first(P.PFAccNo),11),"0")` but it didn't work.

Comment: format(mid(first(P.PFAccNo),10),"0") sorts only 1st digit of number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use expressions in your ORDER BY clause. For test data

```
ID  PFAccNo      
--  -------------
 1  MH/122020/101
 2  MH/122020/2
 3  MH/122020/145
 4  MH/122020/12 
 5  MH/122021/1
```

the query

```sql
SELECT PFAccNo, ID
FROM P
ORDER BY
    Left(PFAccNo,9),
    Val(Mid(PFAccNo,11))
```

returns

```
PFAccNo        ID
-------------  --
MH/122020/2     2
MH/122020/12    4
MH/122020/101   1
MH/122020/145   3
MH/122021/1     5
```

Comment: first(Right(P.PFAccNo,3)) sorting only 2 and 3 digit numbers..MH/122020/2,MH/122020/7 remains unsorted.

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert your substring beginning with pos 11 to a number, and the number can be sorted.

Comment: i had these values stored in table and i want to sort it in select query itself

Comment: problem occured when the number exceeded 99(last 3 digits).

Comment: select cint(mid(datetimestamp,4)) from test_data -- works fine for my testdaa.

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
SELECT 
    tmpTbl.yourFieldName
FROM 
    tmpTbl
ORDER BY 
    CLng(Mid([tmpTbl].[yourFieldname],InStrRev([tmpTbl].[yourFieldname],"/")+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the following data in my test_table, column DATETIMESTAMP:

```
XXX123
YYY000
XXX-1234
```

my Statement:

```
SELECT CInt(Mid(datetimestamp,4)) AS Ausdr1
FROM test_data
ORDER BY 1;
```

sorts my data. please hange 4 to 11 and it will work for you